# Circuit Design Explanation

Tags: analog, sensor, esp32, input, 4-20ma

Can anyone tell me how this circuit will work? I have a AI (analog input) 0-10 V / 4-20 mA and a AO (Analog Output) 0-10 V. I only have one IO pin from ESP32 from which I will use to get AI from a pressure sensor and will control a Fan Via AO circuit.
Basically I am using Onethinx module as MCU and due to limited GPIOs I have to use same GPIO for Analog input and analog output. Someone suggested to make this sort of circuit. But i could not understand how this circuit will work. If software will configure GPIO as AI(Analog input) then it will accept reading from sensor(0-10/4-20mA).And if software configures GPIO as analog output then GPIO will drive a Fan who is connected with AO.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: You can draw schematics using the schematic editor tool just above the text entry field.

Comment: what do you mean by `explanation`? ... what do you expect the circuit to do?

Comment: As long as the components don't have designators or values, it is hard to talk about the circuit.

Comment: Basically I am using Onethinx module as MCU and due to limited GPIOs I have to use one GPIO for Analog input and analog output. Someone suggested to make this sort of circuit. But i could not understand how this circuit will work. If software will configure GPIO as Analog input then it will accept reading from sensor(0-10/4-20mA).

Comment: And if software configures GPIO as analog output then GPIO will drive a Fan who is connected with AO .

Comment: I don't understand how the circuit is supposed to work either. I'm a little confused by the way that you've used the phrases "analog input" and "analog output." It looks to me like your "analog input" is an analog output from a sensor, and your "analog output" is an analog input to a fan controller. Presumably, you choose whether the sensor is configured for 0-10 V output or 4-20 mA output; which of those two options did your friend suggest?

Comment: The biggest problem I expect with the suggested wiring is that if the GPIO pin is configured as a voltage input, then the fan controller circuit will see the same voltage that the GPIO pin sees. The fan controller doesn't seem to have any way of knowing whether the GPIO pin is configured as an output or not.

Comment: If you can propose a better circuit then please do. I am looking for a better solution